# Why Fabric run app terminate?

Tags: python, fabric, pty

I have been trying to start app in remote hosts using Fabric.
I was running a daemonized Java app, which run perfectly fine when I logged in and run it manually. The app keep running even after I exit the session.
But when I use Fabric run(), my app terminates once the session ends.

Although run(command, pty=False) solved my problem (It is roughly documented [here](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work)), I still can not see why these are relevant. I am a python newbie, can anyone explain the difference between:

- start daemon with ssh logged in and start manually
- start daemon using Fabric with pty=True
- start daemon using Fabric with pty=False

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: @NilsWerner, actually its a well known issue documented [here](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work), it is nothing about what I do specifically. However, I want to know WHAT causes this issues and WHY giving up using pty solved this issue?